# iphone+how to sort amount string

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have amount string values like 1000, 100000, 10000000, 5000. the problem is am using sort descriptor for sorting. its sorting properly string wise but after converting to 1k, 10k, 1m, 5k its not working please let me know your suggestion

here is my source code

```
[m_sortTempArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

                NSDictionary *dict1 = obj1;
                NSDictionary *dict2 = obj2;

                NSString *string1 = nil;
                NSString *string2 = nil;
                if (1)
                {
                    if ([[dict1 objectForKey:@"kpiData"] count]>0 && [[dict2 objectForKey:@"kpiData"] count]>0) {

                        string1 = [[[dict1 objectForKey:@"kpiData"] objectAtIndex:kIndex] objectForKey:@"kpiActual"];
                        string2 = [[[dict2 objectForKey:@"kpiData"] objectAtIndex:kIndex] objectForKey:@"kpiActual"];
                    } else {
                        //return 0;
                        string1=@"0";
                        string2=@"0";
                    }
                }

                if ([string2 isEqualToString:@""]){
                    string2 = @"0";
                }

                if ([string1 isEqualToString:@""]){
                    string1 = @"0";
                }


                if ([string1 integerValue]  > [string2 integerValue] ) {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                }

                if ([string1 integerValue]  < [string2 integerValue] ) {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                }
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;

            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SI units you can reconvert those numbers back to floats using the converter in [in this github project](https://github.com/dhoerl/EngineeringNotationFormatter). That code assumes a space between the number and the unit so you will need to modify it. You may find that the conversion to engineering notation is of use as well.